# How fast can my hoard grow?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form

Imagine a game played with tokens. You start with nothing. Every turn, you receive $2^k$ tokens, where $k$ is the total number of tokens you already have. How many tokens do you have after the $n$th turn?

(As an example, the first turn you have zero tokens, so you receive one. The second turn you have one token, so you receive two. The third turn you have three tokens, so you receive eight. The fourth turn you have eleven tokens, so you receive 2048.)

I'm curious if there's a closed form for this. I suspect there isn't, so I'd also be satisfied with the asymptotic growth rate (the "big O"). It certainly seems to grow faster than exponential, but I can't figure out how much faster.

My best attempt at a recursive definition so far is $a_0 = 0$, $a_n = a_{n-1} + 2^{a_{n-1}}$, but this is rather inelegant and hard to do anything with.

(This question came up during a game of *Magic: the Gathering*, using two particular cards: *Anointed Procession* says that if you would "create" a token (put it into play), you "create" twice that many instead, and *Mythos of Illuna* creates a token that's a copy of another card. The virtual tabletop crashes on the fourth iteration, and I'm curious how ridiculous this could get if it kept going.)

Comment: Isn't the recursive definition $a_0 = 0$ and $a_n = a_{n-1} + 2^{a_{n-1}}$ where $a_i$ is the tokens in round $i$

Comment: @JohnWhite Good point, I got that wrong; that's much simpler

Comment: Let us define a second sequence $b_n=0$ and $b_n=2^{b_{n-1}}$. Clearly $a_n\geq b_n$. Now $b_n$ is equal to $2^{2^{2^{2^{⋰^{2^{2^0}}}}}}=2^{2^{2^{2^{⋰^{2}}}}}$, where the number of $2$s in the power tower is $n-1$. This can be better written as $^{n-1}2$, with the superscript at the front representing [Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). Thus we establish that $a_n>^{n-1}2$.

Answer (score 4):

The recursion is given by $a_0 = 0$ and $a_n = a_{n-1} + 2^{a_{n-1}}$

This doesn't seem to have a closed form and Wolfram doesn't think there is one either [[link]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%28n%29%3D+g%28n-1%29+%2B+2%5E%28g%28n-1%29%29+and+g%280%29+%3D+0)

Since $a_{n-1} = o(2^{a_n-1})$, asymptotically, $a_n$ would grow by that function which looks like [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).

$a(n) = \Omega(2^{a(n-1)})$ i.e. it grows at least as fast as tetration. Aymptotically, since the other $a_{n-1}$ is much smaller, it should hold that $a(n) = \Theta(2^{a(n-1)})$

In any case, the tetration function is not elementary so it should not have a closed form in elementary functions.

Comment: So if I'm reading this right, $a(n) = \Theta(^n2)$?

Comment: I feel like big O notation obscures the point here: the important thing for your argument is $a_{n+1}\geq 2^{a_n}$ meaning $a_n$ grows at least as fast as tetration. You're hiding a lot underneath the $O$'s and $\Omega$'s - and the lower bound is fairly clear, but the upper bound is much less clear than the answer makes it out to be. (For instance: $a_n\in O(^n2)$ is false, but reasonable to believe given how this answer is written)

Comment: @MiloBrandt I agree that $O$ hides a lot. But $o$ (little oh) is strictly smaller asymtotically. The lower bound from $\Omega$ should also be helpful. And $\Theta$ is a tight asymptotic bound

Comment: @MiloBrandt:  big O deals well with functions that grow similarly, like when both are polynomial.  It doesn't deal with functions that grow exponentially compared to another.  The exponential growth one will grow incomparably (within the big O notation) compared to the other.

Answer (score 2):

The intuitive answer is that $2^n \gg n$, so $2^n +n\approx 2^n$.  Once you accept that, after $k$ turns you have $2 \uparrow^k 0$ (about, ignoring the few you had before) tokens.  As you say, after four turns you have $0+1+2+8+2048=2059$.  My expression gives $2048$, which is not so different.  When you are talking of fast growing functions, small differences get washed out quickly.

Comment: Formally speaking, $n = o(2^n)$ so $\Theta(n + 2^n)$ should be $\Theta(2^n)$

Comment: @JohnWhite:  while that is correct, I don't think it is useful to OP, which is why I wrote what I did.  If you disagree, please write a better answer.  I am happy to see one, as I think our objective is to help the poster. I have upvoted many competing answers because my standard is that they are correct and they may be helpful.